# c++ Removing characters from string using STL

Tags: c++, stl, stdstring

I'm having a small brain fart: I'd like to remove all instances of the newline character `'\n'` in a `std::string`. I'd prefer to use the STL instead of manual, multi-nested for loops; the only problem is I've forgotten how...

Would `for(...) { std::string::remove_if(...); } ;` work? Could I need to use `std::for_each(...,..., std::string::remove_if(...));`? Or would something else be required?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First idea: the remove/erase idiom:

```
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n'), str.end());
```

Comment: Indeed, this is most likely the best you'll get.

Comment: I needed to use `#include <algorithm>` for this to compile.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Boost.Range it works even shorter:

```
#include <boost\range\algorithm_ext\erase.hpp>

boost::remove_erase(str, '\n');
```

Comment: Also available under the narrower name `boost::range::remove_erase` and through a wider include `boost/range/algorithm_ext.hpp`